# How do I ignore the "redundant parentheses" feature in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm decides that certain parenthesis in my Python code are 'redundant'. I want to keep them anyway. So PyCharm started annoying me with green lines under them. I don't want to give in to PyCharm's quirks.

I was able to ignore other warnings in the following way:

> File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > uncheck all warnings that you don't like..

Sadly, the 'redundant parentheses' warning does not appear in that list.

How do I ignore this warning?

Comment: Just say. Pycharm, **I WILL IGNORE YOU!!!!!**.

Comment: Haha, that's a good one :-)   I wish I could. But I cannot stop my eyes to focus on that annoying green line. It drives me nuts.

Comment: I know your pain :). But seriously though, i think that that feature is built Pycharm, so trying to remove it would be futile.

Comment: They **are** redundant. My eyes would focus on your annoying parentheses! They'd drive me nuts! Please don't write C in Python!

Comment: You _could_ get rid of those (annoying (redundant)) parentheses... but if you don't intend to inflict this cluttered code on other Python programmers, feel free to write it in whichever style you're happy with. :)

Comment: I am a native C programmer.. I love parentheses.

Comment: It is already hard that I cannot use curly braces :-(

Comment: And how about semicolons; surely you end each statement in one; right; :D just press Alt+Enter on the redundant parentheses warning, then enter again and PyCharm *fixes* the problem for you (i.e. removes the unnecessary parentheses from `if`s and `while`s.)

Comment: Well, (if (you (love (parentheses) so) much) here) are a few more. PEP 8 suggests we write for readability. Your code screams "I don't like Python" ...

Comment: YMMV, but I find that it's actually helpful to make my code in each language that I use look distinct. The look of the code subconsciously reinforces the fact that I'm writing in that language, which makes it harder to accidentally use inappropriate syntax or idioms from another language.

Comment: Maybe I should delete my question. I tried, but SO won't let me, because it already contains answers.

Comment: @K.Mulier *never* delete questions that have answers! That's very inconsiderate to those who took the time to work on your problem (and it can also quickly lead to a question-ban for you).

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. I'm sorry. I won't do it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @K.Mulier don't worry about deleting a question -- "where does setting X" exist is a great thing to crowdsource.  I like using braces in my Python code too (don't tell anyone though).  If you haven't checked it out yet, try `from __future__ import braces`.  Or more seriously, if you worried about all of the Python style guide, you'd be writing 80 character, post-it note size lines.

Comment: Your question itself is ok. It's just the practice of using redundant parentheses that we object to. :)

Comment: Seems like the opinions about curly braces, parentheses, semicolons and the like are food for programmer wars :-)    Thanks a lot for the `from __future__ import braces` hint. I'll check that out :-)

Comment: Sometimes redundant parentheses make the code more readable, if they separate logical part of expression. Especially, if lot of similar parts are around in the code. Simple example is when you constatnly check for some point, in which `quadrants` of other points it is, like `x1<x and y1<y` and sometimes you check for combinations like `(x1<x and y1<y) and (x2>x and y2>y)` - in such case they are redundandt, but nicely split the expression to parts, which make more sence

Comment: @gilhad: Sure, there's nothing wrong with using parentheses to logically group things. However, your example isn't quite doing that, since without the parentheses the evaluation would proceed from left to right, stopping if a false-ish result is found before the end of the `and` chain. Of course, that won't change the final result of the expression. FWIW, I'd probably write your example as `x1 < x < x2 and y1 < y < y2` since it's more compact and a little more readable (IMHO). `a < f() < b` is equivalent to `a < f() and f() < b` except that `f()` is only evaluated once.

Comment: The logical value is the same but the meaning could be different - your expression concentrate at the fact, that x,y is between x1,y1 and x2,y2, while mine concentrate on the fact, that x,y is in RIGHT UP quadrant of x1,y1 AND also i in LOWER LEFT quadrant of x2,y2. (yes, it is the same condition, but if your program is more aware about quadrants, then about being between, then it may do it simplier to understand it. And vice versa.) The parentheses shows the intend under the expression (how it should be read/understood by man) more, than how it should be computed by computer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

redundant parenthesis is a *weak warning*. You can just uncheck the box there.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is `redundant parenthesis` under Inspections (PyCharm 2016.1.4). Look closer.

If you still can't find it, there is a search bar on the top left corner of the settings menu. Search for `redun` and the `redundant parenthesis` inspection should come up.

Comment: Waw, thank you!
You are right, I somehow missed the option when searching through the settings. I'm really sorry.